# Facebbook API - Get signed_request but it always return NULL

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using Laravel 4 to build a facebook app.

This is my code in **routes.php**:

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    $facebook = new Facebook(Config::get('facebook'));
    var_dump($facebook->getSignedRequest());
});
```

But it always **return NULL**.

Please help me. Thank you very much :).

Comment: signed_request only exists in Canvas pages and Page Tab apps

Comment: yes, I'm using Page Tab apps. You can see at: i.imgur.com/yPjBmJc.png

Comment: You haven't filled in a page tab url.

Comment: No, I filled this but I deleted it when I capture screen. You can see agian at here: i.imgur.com/Ax7QHbW.png

Comment: And when you go to the Page Tab the page loads in the iframe but doesn't have a signed request?

Comment: Yes :(. I try $facebook->getUser() or $facebook->api('/me'). It's OK but doesn't have a signed request.

Comment: var_dump $_POST and $_GET and see if you have one. And I would suggest that you use Facebook PHP SDK v4

Comment: Result: array(0) { } :(
I'm using PHP SDK v4

Comment: I change Page Tab URL:
http://domain.com/facebook-sdk to http://domain.com/facebook-sdk/index.php. It's OK :D.

But in Laravel, How can I do that?

Comment: Thank you very much. I have a answer ^^.